# Как при помощи yiisoft/yii2-imagine в Yii2 сделать умный ресайз?

Tags: yii2, yii, extension

Собственно задача состоит в том, чтобы при помощи расширения yiisoft/yii2-imagine в Yii2 ресайзить изображение до явно заданной ширины, а вот высота должна просчитываться пропорционально относительно разницы на которую уменьшилась ширина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$img = Image::getImagine()->open('path to file ...');

$size = $img->getSize();
$ratio = $size->getWidth()/$size->getHeight();
$height = round($width/$ratio);

$box = new Box($width, $height);
$img->resize($box)->save($filePath.'/thumb/' . $fileName);

//Или

Image::thumbnail($fullName,$width,$height)->save($filePath.'/thumb/' . $fileName);
```

[Источник](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=476025#answer_476025)